# Hadoop Resource Manager only show 1 node (cluster)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

i have **2 hadoop node** and have started **hdfs** and **yarn**. i see `jps` status in master are below :

```
12642 Jps
11271 NameNode
12075 NodeManager
11421 DataNode
11614 SecondaryNameNode
11775 ResourceManager
```

and jps in slave are below :

```
8445 DataNode
9469 Jps
8574 NodeManager
```

but when see in Hadoop yarn cluster, i see only 1 live node
http://localhost:8088/cluster/nodes and also in http://localhost:50070/

My `yarn-site.xml` :

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>localhost:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>localhost:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>localhost:8088</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>localhost:8031</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
    <value>localhost:8033</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

and `mapred-site.xml` :

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapred.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Note: **on slave, the localhost become master's hostname.**

Any Idea what are miss in my configuration ?

Comment: All your configs point at localhost... I'd suggest looking into Ambari for automated cluster installation with easier configuration management

Comment: @cricket_007 but in slave, i set hostname to master...

Comment: Okay... None of your question configurations use a master reference, though (or slave)